# Installing QGIS plugin when offline

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, installation, offline

Due to various IT policies at my workplace, QGIS is installed on a machine that is not connected to the Internet. I wish to install a couple of QGIS plugins on this system.

I have downloaded the required plugins from http://pyqgis.org/repo/contributed. How do I install them in QGIS?

Comment: I remember something about this on the user list.But can't find it now it seems like one of the devs said they could just place them in tthe plugin folder (unpacked). I'll keep looking

Answer (score 57, accepted):

For **QGIS 3** (see the [Changelog for QGIS 3.0](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog30/index.html#feature-allow-installing-plugins-from-local-zip-packages))

When QGIS 3 is released it will contain a <kbd>Install from Zip</kbd> menu item to remove the need for you to manually do it.

---

You can just extract them into the `.qgis/python/plugins` folder in your home directory.

If you are using QGIS 1.9.0. (available as nightly build) you need to extract the archive into `.qgis2/python/plugins` instead.

The folder structure should look like this:

```
.qgis
├── python
│   └── plugins
│        └──plugin folder
│        └──plugin folder
│        └──plugin folder
```

For example, this is an extract of what mine looks like:

[image]

Comment: A reminder for anyone else who does this: Do remember to enable the plugin from 'Manage Plugins' Menu. Without it, the plugin  won't be visible on the UI.

Comment: `C:\Users\{username}\.qgis\...`

Comment: @NathanW it works : )

Comment: QGIS 2.0 or 2.0.1 the folder is now: - "QGIS Dufour\apps\qgis\python\plugins"

Comment: No the folder is `C:\Users\{username}\.qgis2\`. Don't install into the `QGIS Dufour` folder.

Comment: using  QGIS 2.14.1 , didnt find plugin folder

Comment: Note: on a mac the folders containing the QGIS plugins are hidden. you will have to reveal them. Reference from comment on - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227057/where-is-the-plugins-folder-in-macos

Comment: After doing what @NathanW suggested, I compiled my resources file and put it in the folder with my other plugins. But I cannot find it in the Plugin Manager. I made sure to enable experimental plugins, reloaded the repository, checked to make sure the version is correct.  Any suggestion?

Comment: For me the right folder was => C:\Users\<Name>\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins. Then I activated it in the "Manage and Install Plugins" Menu. Windows 10 Qgis 3.22