# Where to install python plugins without internet access?

Tags: qgis, python, installation

I have a problem where I have no internet access. [In the thread regarding a similar subject](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26979/how-to-install-a-qgis-plugin-when-offline), it was mentioned that the plugin .zip file should be extracted to the ".qgis/python/plugins" in the home directory. Where would I find the "home" directory.

Answer (score 1):

Home will be something like

```
C:\Users\username\
```

on Windows or

```
/home/username/
```

on Linux.

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\username in XP

Answer (score 1):

on Mac OS X

```
/users/username/.qgis/
```