# Using Google Maps Offline in QGIS

Tags: qgis, google-maps

I am working on a QGIS project that involves me using the Google Hybrid Map Plug-in. I am due to spend time travelling over the next few days and won't have an internet connection. I was hoping someone could let me know if it's possible to continue using the plug-in without internet? For example by saving the relatively small I need for offline use.

Thanks
Sarah

Comment: Not sure Google Terms of Use would allow it - you can use OpenStreetMap or your own purchased imagery in Offline mode in QGIS. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26979/how-to-install-a-qgis-plugin-when-offline

Answer (score 1):

You will need to save the OpenStreetMaps (or whatever images you are able to legally use) for the area that you are interested in onto your machine.  Use Project>Save as Image to save what is in your map view as a georeferenced image.  You'll probably want to save the maps at different resolutions so that you'll have some zooming in/out ability.