# Where is the plugins folder in macOS?

Tags: qgis-plugins, installation, mac

Installed QGis on macbook pro. If I needed to reinstall or modify a plugin, where is the plugins folder located?

Comment: As with other OS, in the .qgis folder, `/Users/you/.qgis2/python/plugins`. It is a Unix hidden folder ([View Hidden Files and Folders on Your Mac With Terminal](https://www.lifewire.com/view-hidden-mac-folders-using-terminal-2260776))