# installing plugins manually

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, mac, qgis-2.18

I'm running QGIS Las Palmas on Mac OS Mavericks but after enabling all features in the Manage Plugins menu, I can't find the plugin I want.
I downloaded it from the internet and wish to install it manually. From what I understood I should be able to reach the plugins folder in qgis/contents/python/plugins but i don't have a python folder when I open 'contents'.
All I have is qgis/contents/plugins and then a bunch of other folders, but no python.

Can anyone guide me through manually installing the plugin on the correct folder, please?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new "python" folder inside "contents"? From some of the posts I read, you might need `Contents/Resources/python/plugins` but can't confirm this :)

Comment: Does this help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227057/where-is-the-plugins-folder-in-macos (the implication is that the folder is a hidden one which is why you can't see it).