# EasyCustomLabeling-2.0 plugin installation

Tags: qgis-plugins

I've downloaded EasyCustomLabeling-2.0 but I don't know how to activate the plugin or where files should be placed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the latest version was ported to the next version of QGIS, which none of us are running.

You should replace it with the previous version:

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/EasyCustomLabeling/version/1.3.5/

Depending on your operating system, installing the plugin involves copying the un-zipped folder here:

C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis\python\plugins

or check this for a Linux version:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/26981/9880

You might have to go into the Plugins menu and 'enable' it.

Then you'll see this icon on your Labeling toolbar:

[image]