# Packaging newer version of QGIS with custom plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, installation

Once in a while my company updates QGIS to the latest LR/LTR version. Besides that we also have some domestic plugins written for internal users.

Is there a way to update QGIS to that LTR version together with domestic plugins? So, the user won't need to install that plugin every time.

---

**References:**

- [Installing QGIS plugin when offline](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26979/installing-qgis-plugin-when-offline)

Comment: what about making a custom plugin repo to ease install for users ?

Comment: @Maximilienjaffrès, thank you for an idea, but can describe the *"to ease install"* a bit more in details?

Comment: QGIS plugins are installed in (on Windows) `%APPDATA%\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins`. This directory isn't removed when you upgrade QGIS version, so, all customization will not change (database connexions, favorite directories, toolbars, spatial bookmarks, etc.). And plugins, if the maximum version in metadata is compatible, will be already installed on the new version.

Comment: Hmmm sounds easy, i will need to test it

Comment: @J.Monticolo can you please convert your comment into an answer ?!